# How to receive KendoGrid serverPaging request on server side

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, sparql

I have a kendoGrid object being initialized where serverPaging is set to `true`. However, my remote web service which is called through the `read` property of kendoGrid's `datasource` property loads an entire tree of JSON every time the server request is made. This service makes a SPARQL request which queries against an ontology-type database. My SPARQL query is hardcoded; hence, in order to receive kendoGrid's page instance, I need to pass the page into my query. The C# function looks like this:

```
public ResponseData[] RetrieveAllColumns()
    {
        DataManagerClient dmsClient = new DataManagerClient();
        QueryRequestContract qryRequest = new QueryRequestContract
        {
            Graph = "someGraphName",
            WithImports = true,
            DataFormatType = DataFormatTypes.JSON,
            Sparql = @"SELECT DISTINCT ?result ?label ?table ?state ?schema ?database ?server
                        WHERE { ?result a database_onto:Column . 
                                ?result rdfs:label ?label . 
                                ?tableVar database_onto:tableHasColumn ?result .
                                ?tableVar rdfs:label ?table . 
                                ?result database_onto:columnHasState ?stateVar .
                                ?stateVar rdfs:label ?state .
                                ?schemaVar database_onto:schemaHasTable ?tableVar .
                                ?schemaVar rdfs:label ?schema .
                                ?databaseVar database_onto:databaseHasSchema ?schemaVar .
                                ?databaseVar rdfs:label ?database .
                                ?serverVar database_onto:serverHasDatabase ?databaseVar .
                                ?serverVar rdfs:label ?server .
                            } ORDER BY (LCASE(?label))" // serverPaging would be added here as OFFSET and LIMIT for the query
        };

        QueryResponseContract qryResponse = dmsClient.Query(qryRequest);
        RDFServiceResponse jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RDFServiceResponse>(qryResponse.ReturnData);
        List<ResponseData> lstRspData = new List<ResponseData>();

        foreach (BindingsObj bndData in jsonData.results.bindings)
        {
            lstRspData.Add(new ResponseData
            {
                Name = Regex.Replace(bndData.label.value, @"\(.*?\)", ""),
                Link = bndData.result.value,
                Table = bndData.table != null ? Regex.Replace(bndData.table.value, @"\(.*?\)", "") : null,
                State = bndData.state != null ? bndData.state.value : null,
                Database = bndData.database != null ? Regex.Replace(bndData.database.value, @"\(.*?\)", "") : null,
                Schemas = bndData.schema != null ? Regex.Replace(bndData.schema.value, @"\(.*?\)", "") : null,
                Server = bndData.server != null ? Regex.Replace(bndData.server.value, @"\(.*?\)", "") : null
            });
        }

        return lstRspData.ToArray();
    }
```

;where `ResponseData[]` is the array model and `RDFServiceResponse` is the RDF array model.

This is my controller:

```
public CountResponse Get()
{
    return this.cmlData.RetrieveColumnTotal();
}
```

To reiterate my question, how can I pass KendoGrid's Datasource paging properties (page instance and page size specifically) to my service so that I can make the necessary adjustments to my server-side query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `serverPaging: true` on your Kendo UI Grid, then `skip`, `take`, and `page` are appended as query string parameters in the URL of your GET request automatically.

```
http://localhost/controller/CountResponse?skip=0&take=100&page=1
```

All you need to do is add those parameters by name to your controller action and handle them server-side so that you are only returning the page of data the client requested.

```
public CountResponse Get(int skip, int take) {
  return this.cmlData.RetrieveColumnTotal(skip, take);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is clearer than Kendo's [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-serverPaging) for serverPaging

Comment: @Xenyal Don't forget to return a `total` property in your response; otherwise, the grid pager will not work properly. What I do is I wrap the response in an object, i.e. `{ data: [/*your data*/], total: 100 }`.

Comment: Does the `total` property refer to the total number of items returned? Or just the total number of items displayed?

Comment: @Xenyal It should refer to the total count of items the query returns, not the actual number you are returning. So, if your grid is to show 20 items per page, and your query returns 100 items, your controller action will return the 20 items for the page specified, but `total` will equal 100. This way, the Kendo UI Grid will know how many page buttons to display at the bottom and how to set the `skip`, `take`, and `page` parameters for future queries. I hope that made sense.

Comment: That did, I noticed the paging number was off before. Thanks! Will be sure to implement that.